# Convert a folder of images into a multi-page pdf file using command line tools?

Tags: command-line, pdf, image-manipulation, jpeg

I have a folder with 100 jpg images. I want to convert these images into a multi-page pdf file, with all the images (cropped to A4 size). They are already in the correct rotation.

Which tools should I use?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Requirements

ImageMagick

Type the follow line to commmand prompt for intall ImageMagick:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Convert from jpegs to PDF:

Go to the work directory (directory of jpegs):

```
cd work/directory/path
```

Convert the JPG files to PDF:

```
convert *.jpg foo.pdf
```

source : http://bitprison.net/jpg_to_pdf

Comment: Hmm, does not yet crop to A4 aspect ratio though ;)

Comment: If you have the images in sub folders use this `convert */*.jpg foo.pdf`

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately **`convert`** changes the image before so to have minimal loss of quality, i.e. the quality of the original `jpg`, you need to use `img2pdf`, I use this commands:

**A shorter one liner solution using only `img2pdf`**

Make PDF

`img2pdf *.jp* --output combined.pdf`

Optionally add OCR to the output PDF

`ocrmypdf combined.pdf combined_ocr.pdf`

**This was the original commands with more command and more tools needed:**

1. This to make a `pdf` file out of every `jpg` image without loss of either resolution or quality:

   `ls -1 ./*jpg | xargs -L1 -I {} img2pdf {} -o {}.pdf`
2. This to concatenate the `pdf`pages into one:

   `pdftk *.pdf cat output combined.pdf`
3. And last I add an OCRed text layer that doesn't change the quality of the scan in the pdfs so they can be searchable:

   `pypdfocr combined.pdf`

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't crop pages to A4 size :/

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend the Python CLI program `img2pdf` for lossless conversion:

https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf

Example usage:

```
img2pdf img1.png img2.jpg -o out.pdf
```